# React + Typescript: How to define interface for an array that's populated from componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am exploring React and Typescript and I stuck on a problem of how to define an interface for an array where are stored data from an API.

Here's what I have:

```
interface IState {
  loadingData: boolean;
  apiData: Array<string>;
}

class Contact extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loadingData: true,
      apiData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('This is your data', data);
        this.setState({ loadingData: false, apiData: data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error));
  }
  ...
```

After running this code, though, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, username, email, address, phone, website, company}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at Contact.tsx:39)
    in div (at Contact.tsx:33)
    in Contact (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at Main.tsx:26)
    in div (at Main.tsx:23)
    in div (at Main.tsx:16)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (at Main.tsx:15)
    in Main (at src/index.tsx:9)
```

What's the key to properly set up an interface for an array?

**EDIT:** Adding the `render` function:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h5>API Data</h5>
          {this.state.loadingData ? (
              'Loding data...'
            ) : (
              this.state.apiData
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: please post the render function, where the error is located

Comment: @Jerome added, thanks.

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40746168/691711.

Comment: in render, it should {this.state.apidata && this.state.apiData.map((data:IApiData) =>{ return (<div key={data.id}>{data.whatever}</div> }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render an `array` in react.

```
{this.state.loadingData ? (
   'Loding data...'
  ) : (
    this.state.apiData 
     && this.state.apiData.map(item => <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
  )
}
```

`this.state.apiData && this.state.apiData.map` will check if apiData exists (not falsy, this won't protect you from it being a wrong type) and then run call the map.

And you need to update your interface

```
interface IState {
  loadingData: boolean;
  apiData: ApiData[];
}

interface ApiData {
  id: string
  name: string
  ...
}
```